# Where does these functions? "variables"? come from?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I haven´t been able to find this anywhere (mainly because i don´t know what to search for), but when i was reading on W3Schools i stumbled upon the following piece of code:

```
$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

Then i wondered the $result, what is that? where does it come from?

When i search for "$result mysqli" nothing helpful really appears...

I´m used to $ being the sign for variables, but this clearly ain´t defined anywhere in the code. Is it some way of calling a function?

Comment: It comes from `$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)`, right there in the code you posted.

Comment: You should read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

Comment: Whenever the `$variable` appears at the left of a `=`, it has been assigned.

Comment: You do not have to declare variables in PHP.

Comment: @Chevi So in this code they define a new variable in the if statement?

Comment: As the other comments suggested the assignment is in the if statement. This is not good practice because it can be overlooked (like in  your case) or it can be interpreted as a mistake and corrected to `$result == mysqli_query($con,$sql)` which would then result in an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` is a function call.  The tip-off that this is a function call is the parentheses following the function name.

When the code hits that phrase it calls some other PHP code called `mysqli_query` (which is in a library somewhere).  That code receives from your program two values (the $con and $sql values, performs some actions and returns a newly-created value (an object containing information about and results of your query).

That value is then assigned to the variable $result.

Comment: This makes sense when i also read @chevi ´s comments. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This variable is a PHP object, and it contains the result of a sql query. 
Thanks to this you can extract data from a data base

Answer (score 1):

The variable is assigned right here:

```
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```

You may be more used to this construct:

```
if ($foo == $bar)
```

That's a comparison (double equal sign `==`).

However, assignments can happen perfectly well inside an `if` statement as well. The assignment expression will return the assigned value as a result which is then used for `if`. So:

```
if ($foo = bar())
```

is equivalent to

```
$foo = bar();
if ($foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

$result is an array which got values from the mysqli_query.

Php's mysqli extension functions are used to run queries with the database. You need configure a connection before running any queries.

Comment: All of this is done, i just took the piece of the code that confused me.